# Class as a decorator for regular functions and coroutines in Python

Tags: python-asyncio, python-3.7, python-decorators

I am trying to create a class as a decorator that will apply a try-except block to the decorated function and retain some log of the exceptions. I want to apply the decorator to both regular functions as well as to coroutines.

I have done the class-as-decorator and it works as designed for regular functions, but something is going wrong with coroutines. Below is some reduced code for a reduced version of the class-as-decorator and a couple of use cases:

```
import traceback
import asyncio
import functools

class Try:

    def __init__(self, func):
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"applying __call__ to {self.func.__name__}")
        try:
            return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(f"{self.func.__name__} failed")
            print(traceback.format_exc())

    def __await__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"applying __await__ to {self.func.__name__}")
        try:
            yield self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(f"{self.func.__name__} failed")
            print(traceback.format_exc())

# Case 1
@Try
def times2(x):
    return x*2/0

# Case 2
@Try
async def times3(x):
    await asyncio.sleep(0.0001)
    return x*3/0

async def test_try():
    return await times3(10)

def main():
    times2(10)
    asyncio.run(test_try())
    print("All done")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Here's the output of the above code (with minor edits):

```
applying __call__ to times2
times2 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-3-37071526b2e6>", line 14, in __call__
    return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "<ipython-input-3-37071526b2e6>", line 30, in times2
    return x*2/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

applying __call__ to times3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "[...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3296, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-3-37071526b2e6>", line 46, in <module>
    main()
  File "<ipython-input-3-37071526b2e6>", line 43, in main
    asyncio.run(test_try())
  File "[...]/lib/python3.7/asyncio/runners.py", line 43, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "[...]/lib/python3.7/asyncio/base_events.py", line 579, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "<ipython-input-3-37071526b2e6>", line 39, in test_try
    return await times3(10)
  File "<ipython-input-3-37071526b2e6>", line 36, in times3
    return x*3/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Case 1 behaves normally: as expected `__call__` is called, then the decorated function which fails and the exception is caught. But I can't explain the behaviour of Case 2. Notice the missing "times3 failed" and "All done" print at the end. I can't reproduce the color coded output here but Case 1's traceback is regular print while Case 2's traceback is exception red (on PyCharm). The surprising part is that the `__call__` method was called instead of `__await__`.

I have tried another class-as-decorator, one that keeps a tally of the number of times a function was called. That works just fine with `__call__` with either regular functions or coroutines.

So what is actually going on? Do I need to somehow force the function to use `__await__`? How?

I tried the following:

```
async def test_try2():
    func = await times3
```

with output

```
applying __await__ to times3
times3 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-5-5a85f988097e>", line 22, in __await__
    yield self.func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: times3() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'
```

which does force using `__await__` but then what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it places `__await__` on the wrong object. Generally `await f(x)` expands to something like:

```
_awaitable = f(x)
_iter = _awaitable.__await__()
yield from _iter  # not literally[1]
```

Note how `__await__()` is called on the *result* on the function, not on the function object itself. What happens in your `times3` example is the following:

- `__call__` calls the original `times3` coroutine function in `self.func`, which trivially constructs a coroutine object. There is no exception at this point because the object didn't start executing yet, so a [coroutine object](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#coroutine-objects) (what you get by calling an `async def` coroutine function) is returned.
- `__await__` is invoked on the coroutine object obtained by running `self.func`, which is the original `times3` `async def`, and not on your function wrapper. This is because, in terms of the pseudocode above, your wrapper corresponds to `f`, whereas `__await__()` is invoked on the `_awaitable`, which in your case is the result of calling `f`.

In general you can't know whether the result of a function call will ever be awaited. But since coroutine objects are not useful for anything other than awaiting them (and they even print a warning when destroyed without being awaited), you can safely assume so. This assumption allows your `__call__` to check whether the result of the function call is awaitable and, if so, wrap it in an object that will implement your wrapping logic on the `__await__` level:

```
...
import collections.abc

class Try:
    def __init__(self, func):
        functools.update_wrapper(self, func)
        self.func = func

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"applying __call__ to {self.func.__name__}")
        try:
            result = self.func(*args, **kwargs)
        except:
            print(f"{self.func.__name__} failed")
            print(traceback.format_exc())
            return
        if isinstance(result, collections.abc.Awaitable):
            # The result is awaitable, wrap it in an object
            # whose __await__ will call result.__await__()
            # and catch the exceptions.
            return TryAwaitable(result)
        return result

class TryAwaitable:
    def __init__(self, awaitable):
        self.awaitable = awaitable

    def __await__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print(f"applying __await__ to {self.awaitable.__name__}")
        try:
            return yield from self.awaitable.__await__()
        except:
            print(f"{self.awaitable.__name__} failed")
            print(traceback.format_exc())
```

This results in the expected output:

```
applying __call__ to times3
applying __await__ to times3
times3 failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wrap3.py", line 30, in __await__
    yield from self.awaitable.__await__()
  File "wrap3.py", line 44, in times3
    return x*3/0
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

Note that your implementation of `__await__` had an unrelated problem, it delegated to the function using `yield`. One must use `yield from` instead, because that allows the underlying iterable to choose when to suspend, and also to provide a value once it stops suspending. A bare `yield` suspends unconditionally (and only once) which is incompatible with the semantics of `await`.

<sup>1</sup>
*Not literally* because `yield from` is not allowed in `async def`. But `async def` behaves as if such a generator was returned by the `__await__` method of the object it returns.

Comment: Hey @user4815162342, thanks for the answer, it does the job when it comes to handling exceptions, however when there are no exceptions there is no return value, it's None. Any way to fix that?

Comment: @gorune It was just an oversight, the `yield from` should have been preceded by a `return` to actually transfer the final value to the awaiter. I've now updated the answer.

Comment: Ok, I found I had to just do:

`this = yield from self.awaitable.__await__()
 return this`

But it's weird I thought yield from should have returned automatically. Is this normal behaviour?

Edit, thanks, I see it :)

Comment: @gorune No, `yield from` is like `await`, it either yields to the parent generator (and ultimately the event loop) or provides a value in the current context. The latter is specific to `yield from` and was introduced to support the `await` use case. Before `yield from` generators didn't have a "return value", `return <x>` was a syntax error. Later `await` was introduced and generator-style coroutines were (rightfully) banished to obscure use cases of writing or exploring low-level code. Even this example could be written without it, for example [like this](https://pastebin.com/H5RuvsQh).